# Enterprise Architect: How do I add my included assemblies (C# .NET 4) so I can use them?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, enterprise-architect

I'm using Enterprise Architect 9.0.904. I created a new project and it has a section in the Class Models labeled "Frameworks" and a note beside it stating:

> Class libraries, APIs and other
>   re-usable components

Yet, it isn't really intuitive on how I can put my dll files I plan to use in the project in there. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

If you're after getting a UML representation of the contents of an existing DLL, then you do that by selecting "Import Binary Module" under the Code Engineering menu.

If you just need to describe the execution environment of your code, that's best done in a deployment diagram.